# Is there any view can contain a recyclerview to handle showing or hiding status?

Tags: android, layout, view, android-recyclerview, spinner

As the title saying , I need a view to hide or show a recyclerview.
Like Spinner.

And I can only show/hide the recyclerview by clicking it.
(It should be a line like Spinner.)

The following image would be more comprehensive.

[image]

Is there any way to reach this?

Comment: You can simply set visibility for recyclerview on button click with animation

Comment: but using button looks ugly, can I have something similar with Spinner?

Comment: You can use 9 patch image for button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a custom toggle button with different drawables based on what state the button is in. You have to use a selector like this:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_pressed"
          android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_focused"
          android:state_focused="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_default" />
</selector>
```

See the documentation here: [Custom Background](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/button.html)

Then you set the visibility on the other view in the onClick event for the button to View.GONE/View.VISIBLE

Answer (score 0):

```
 recylerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
 recylerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Comment: I know this,but how can I get that "a line with a triangle" view like Spinner?